# disable edit on mysql after given period

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed an data capture form using phprunner and data is updated on mysql database.

Due to typos during entry, I have allowed users to only edit their own data and further restricted this to one field (the free text and error prone one).

Is it possible to set a lock on records after a given period say 1 day.
The goal here would be to set a sort of expiry on user "edit" ability and so historical reports pulled from stored records can always be the same.

If so how can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a date-entered column in the table (use NOW() for the current time) and check it when users try to update their post. Use [date_add() or date_sub()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to calculate the time difference.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I am using a timestamp field to capture date. How can the check be enforced to deny edit/update....I am a newbie in mysql so forgive me if its obvious..

Comment: I'm not familiar with a MYSQL way to do it. I would just check it using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Create a date created column and then check to see the datediff between that date and today's date. If it is greater than one then you can lock it using php or something:

```
if ($timeDiff greater than a day){
    disable edit button
else
    enable edit button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple method is to simply check if the record CAN be editted in the first place. e.g. when you build the edit form, check how long ago the record was created. If it's > 1day, then output "sorry, editing disabled" instead of the form.

In case your've got relatively smart users who can fake up the form and submit the data anyways, you can then also do filtering at the sql `update` level to disallow changes:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET ...
WHERE (id = $id) AND ((record_created + interval 1 day) > now())
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B. Will use php and mysql filters as described

Answer (score 0):

This will only prevent the database from been updated but will not hide the user "update/submit" button

```
 UPDATE table
    SET  ...
 where last_update < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
      And id = $id
```

To hide the button from the user you could (on the front end)

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    IF(last_update < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), 1, 0) as show_update_button
    .....
```